# amsmath equation identation wrong with text

Tags: align, amsmath, indentation

I have a problem creating an equation, where I first want to write it as text and then resolve it to numbers.

This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[headings=small,12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mtxt}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mtxt{Total Size} & =\mtxt{Text1} & + \mtxt{Text2} & + \mtxt{Text3} & + \mtxt{Text4} & + \mtxt{Text5}\\
& = 1 & + 2 & + 3 & + 4 & + 5
\end{aligned}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Problem is, that the first alignment is correct, the third one is too, but the other ones aren't.

[image: result image]

This is the result and clearly not what I wished for, but I diving into many aligned articles I still cannot grasp why this is happening.

Edit:
Expected is that indentation aligns after each `&`, so the plus signs align with enough space for each cell in the column there.
Like seen in the picture Christian Hupfer and also the one by Steven B. Segletes.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should tell us what you expect!

Comment: the example isn't what the code produces.  for one thing, the code specifies `\textsc` and the example shows ordinary lowercase.

Comment: You are right. thats because I shortly switched the mtxt command to \text to try it out if that was the reason, but it wasnt. But thats why I did the command, to fast switch it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should bear in mind that `aligned` makes pairs of columns, one right aligned and one left aligned, adding space between each pair.

You want `alignat` that doesn't add space between pairs of columns, but jumping over the right aligned columns.

```
\documentclass[headings=small,12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mtxt}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{5}
\mtxt{Total Size} & =\mtxt{Text1} && + \mtxt{Text2} && + \mtxt{Text3} && + \mtxt{Text4} && + \mtxt{Text5}\\
& = 1 && + 2 && + 3 && + 4 && + 5
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted this because it works, looks more clean and because you explained what is happening, though Christian Hupfer's answer is also correct and working

Answer (score 4):

Unclear what is requested, so this is a trial with `alignat`:

(**Note**: The spacing between `+` and the Text has to be changed)

```
\documentclass[headings=small,12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mtxt}[1]{\text{\textsc{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{5}
\mtxt{Total Size} & =\mtxt{Text1} & +& \mtxt{Text2} & +& \mtxt{Text3} & +& \mtxt{Text4} & +& \mtxt{Text5}\\
& = 1 & +& 2 & +& 3 & +& 4 & +& 5
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is working, but it increments the equation counter each line. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: @Crumar: Either use `alignedat` within `equation` as egreg suggested or say `\nonumber` after the number '5' in your second line.

Comment: the spacing around the plus signs is too tight.  you could fix that by inputting them as `{}+{}` but really, doubling the `&` just before each plus is easier.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks (as usual!), but I've wrote already in my post: The spacing must be changed -- I leave this to the O.P.

Answer (score 1):

Done here with two varieties of TABstack, namely a `\tabbedCenterstack` with left alignment, and a `\tabularCenterstack`.  Note that proper spacing around the `+` and `=` signs have been achieved.

```
\documentclass[headings=small,12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand{\mtxt}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\TABbinaryLeft
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{
  \mtxt{Total Size} & =\mtxt{Text1} & + \mtxt{Text2} & + \mtxt{Text3} & 
  + \mtxt{Text4} & + \mtxt{Text5}\\
& = 1 & + 2 & + 3 & + 4 & + 5
}
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
\TABbinary\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\tabularCenterstack{rclclclclc}{
  \mtxt{Total Size} =& \mtxt{Text1} & +& \mtxt{Text2} & +& \mtxt{Text3} & 
  +& \mtxt{Text4} & +& \mtxt{Text5}\\
=&  1 & +& 2 & + &3 & + &4 & +& 5
}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

By way of explanation, a `\TABbinaryLeft` places a `{}` at the beginning of every field, to activate the binary nature of fields starting with a `+` or `=`.  A `\TABbinary` places a `{}` at the beginning and end of every field, for fields beginning in a `+` and ending in a `=`, for example.  The default package behavior is `\TABbinaryRight`, which is why the default tab character placement should occur (by default) *after* operators.

Also, the `\setstacktabulargap{0pt}` setting removes the default `\tabcolsep` separation between adjacent columns of a `\tabularCenterstack`, which is desired for setting maths.

Comment: I want to try this, even though it looks a lot like too much effort for me. Unfortunately, the effort even increases. On the CTAN page of the package (which as I saw you are maintaining), it say it is included in MikTex, but the package tabstackengine is not found. MikTex doesnt offer to download it, and a search in the package manager did also not yield results. As I tend to switch between machines while writing, it is a lot of effort to maintan all packages everywhere :/

Comment: @Crumar It is there, at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine.  I don't know why MikTeX won't download it (maybe your installation is old).  But you can manually place the .sty in your working directory for now.  Default installation with MikTeX would be in `C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\tabstackengine`